# Link to page coordinates

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Is there a way to link to another page's content using coordinates, without using #anchors? For example, say I want the link to go directly to content that's 1200px down the page. How can I do this? Javascript, server-side magic, anything goes as long as it will work for the average visitor.

Comment: OP here.

What about loading the page in a frame, then using the frame to insert javascript?

Anything server-side could work too. For example, a php script that grabs a page, puts a javascript scroll function in the bottom of it and then rewrites the url to match the page?

Not trying to get exploitative, I just think this would be a really neat trick to pull off.

Comment: Assume that I don't have control over the page directly, by the way.

Comment: A related topic is scrolling directly to a search term. Is that possible, without having direct control of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Store the coords in a hash

e.g. http://example.com/page#123

Then via javascript, scroll the window

```
window.onload = function(){
  var pos = window.location.hash.substring(1); //get hash & remove #
  window.scroll(0,pos);
};
```

Comment: Yea, unfortunately my solution requires JS to be injected into the page either by extension of the browser or addition to the website by the webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a browser plugin or extension that would allow you do it, for the people who've installed it at least. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the other website, you could write a javascript that looks at the query string for a parameter (i.e. ?y=1200) and scrolls the page to that position, but I'm guessing you don't have access to the other site?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with UserJS (Greasemonkey):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/##scroll-y:1200
```

But users must install script before.

Answer (score 0):

The browser same origin policy will prevent you from scrolling a frame or iframe displaying content from a different domain.  The most reliable method would be to have your server fetch the page and insert the scrolling code.